# IDAPython script does not reload

Tags: ida, idapython

I'm debugging an IDAPython script on my host machine and I have IDA running on my Windows VM. The folder containing the IDAPython script on the host machine is shared with the VM.

The first time I run the IDAPython script in IDA it works fine. However, for subsequent runs a cached version of the script seems to be running. I end up having to close and re-start IDA in order for the changes to get loaded up. Is there an easier way? I run scripts as `File > Open Script file.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `idaapi.require("module_name")` to reload the script.
There is more information about it in the HexBlog article, [*Loading your own modules from your IDAPython scripts with idaapi.require()*](https://hex-rays.com/blog/loading-your-own-modules-from-your-idapython-scripts-with-idaapi-require/).